Why is opening & closing connection with Websockets API in Cypress Test Runner so flaky?
I'm using Cypress to directly connect to websocket server using browser's websocket API. In my implementation one 'it' block is one test step and one 'describe' block is one test (I know that's unusual.)
E.g.:
const ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);


 it("Send a message to WSS", (done) => {
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send(Message);
      done();
    };
  });

 it("Close WSS connection", (done) => {
    ws.close();

    ws.onclose = () => {
      done();
    };
  });`

Everything works fine when I run the tests individually in Test Runner, but when I run a test suite w/ multiple tests (each test opening & closing the connection) more often than not the first test passes and the 2nd fails upon establishing connection. I'm getting back 200 w/ a failed handshake message.
But it's very flaky. Sometimes 2 tests pass and the 3rd one fails. Sometimes they all pass.
I'd be grateful for any ideas or workarounds.
I tried hard waiting after each test/each file w/ 1 describe block so the session clears in the infrastructure but to no avail.

If you want to use describe() blocks as the "test" and it() blocks as the "step", you will need to set test isolation off at the describe() level.
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')

describe('this sequence of tests are connected', {testIsolation: false}, () => {

 it("Send a message to WSS", (done) => {
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send(Message);
      done();
    };
  })

 it("Close WSS connection", (done) => {

    ws.onclose = () => {
      done();
    };

    ws.close();       // also reverse the order of these lines 
                      // (event listener is set up before the event is triggered)
  })
})

Test isolation is designed to clear down variables between tests, to prevent unexpected results due to data crossing over the test boundary.
Since you are defining your test differently to the way Cypress expects them (which is one test per it() block), you need to signal that intention to the test runner. The test isolation flag is the way to do that.
The reason why you get flaky results is probably due to using WS events, which fire asynchronously to the test code, although you are correctly using done() to indicate to the test that it needs to wait for the webSocket event before completing.

Thx for the answer. Yeah, I think I'm correctly using done() to indicate to the test that it needs to wait for the webSocket event before completing and then  I would expect the tests to not be flaky. Maybe it's something with the server's config. No clue.

So in the Cypress Test Runner, it appears that all three WebSocket connections are being established at the beginning of the first test because the
const ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);

statement is executed immediately when the test file is loaded. This is outside of any specific test (it block), so it runs as soon as the script is parsed, not when the tests are actually executed.
So the answer is that the connection to wss has to be in an 'it' block otherwise it will be  executed for all tests at once at the beginning of test suite execution.
E.g.:
let ws;

// Pre-conditions & action
it("Connect to & send a message", (done) => {
    ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
    ws.onopen = () => {
        ws.send(message);
        done();
    };
});

